# Is there a public key semantically secure cryptosystem for which one can prove in zero knowledge the equivalence of two plaintexts?

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs, semantic-security, mental-poker, pohlig-hellman-cipher

If Alice encrypts two messages $a$ and $b$, such that $x=E(a)$, $y=E(b)$. Can Alice prove (without revealing $a$, $b$ or the private key) that $a = b$?

Obviously the proof must not be too long and it should be practical to compute and verify (either interactively or non-interactively).

This is possible for the Pohlig-Hellman symmetric cipher, even if the ciphertexts are encrypted with different keys. But P-H is not public key.

If such a cryptosystem exists (and it is commutative or provides public re-encryption),  then one of the limitations in Mental Poker protocols could be solved. The problem is the existence (or not) of a protocol that can provide both semantic security and abrupt drop out tolerance (without any threshold scheme).
**Edit:** It seems that the encryption needs to be deterministic to be able to support drop-out tolerance, and I see no way to overcome this. Without determinism, I was only able to veto the cards of a single player from a new deck.

See [What is the theoretical and practical status of mental poker?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/what-is-the-theoretical-and-practical-status-of-mental-poker/4001#4001) for a related question.

Comment: Would it have to be zero knowledge, or would it be enough if semantic security was preserved? $\:$

Comment: It does not need to be perfect zero knowledge. I suppose semantic security is enough. A computational zero knowledge argument will do fine.

Comment: (Note than an argument system could preserve semantic security without $\hspace{1.9 in}$ even being computationally zero knowledge.) $\:$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Such proofs are possible for El Gamal.

It involves a zero knowledge proof of equality of a discrete log, together with the homomorphic property of El Gamal encryption.

Recall that given $E(a)$ and $E(b)$, anyone can form $E(a/b)$ using the homomorphic property of El Gamal.  Suppose $E(a/b)=(r,s)=(g^k,h^k a/b)$ (where $g$ is the generator and $h$ is the public key).  Then proving that $a=b$ is equivalent to proving that $a/b=1$, i.e., that $(r,s)=(g^k,h^k)$ for some $k$, or in other words, that $(g,h,r,s)$ is a Diffie-Hellman 4-tuple.  There is a standard zero-knowledge protocol to prove this fact.  That's all you need.

Comment: That is a cool construction. You could do the same thing with Paillier. Prove that $E(a-b)=0$. My [thep](https://code.google.com/p/thep/) library has a ZKP for set membership which should serve that purpose well (use a set of just $0$).

Answer (score 2):

You are in a twist here:

- semantic security (equal to IND-CPA) can only be fulfilled by probabilistic encryption schemes.
- You need a deterministic encryption scheme for your drop-out tolerance.

As it was pointed out previously, any homomorphic encryption allows you to proof in zero knowledge the equality of two ciphertexts:

- known: $c_0 = E(x,r_0)\;,\;c_1 = E(x,r_1)$
- Prover: commits $c_2 = E(x,r_2)$
- Verifier: flip a coin for bit $b$.
- Prover: decommit $(c_2 - c_b)$ by showing the according random coin $r_d$ (this is usually $r_d = r_2 - r_b$)
- Verifier: check if $E(0,r_d) = c_2 - c_b$. ('0' stands for the neutral element)

With deterministic encryption it is trivial, two plaintexts are equal if and only if their ciphertexts are equal. But this is not IND-CPA.

Answer (score 1):

With any convergent encryption algorithm E, it's easy for Alice to prove -- without revealing(*) a, b or the private key -- that a == b.

In order for the data deduplication feature to work, convergent algorithms are specifically designed such that
when Alice encrypts two messages a and b, such that x=E(a), y=E(b),
then x == y whenever a == b.

There's some discussion here under the tag [convergent-encryption](/questions/tagged/convergent-encryption) and on other stackexchange sites. ( ["Online backup : how could encryption and de-duplication be compatible?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/online-backup-how-could-encryption-and-de-duplication-be-compatible) ).

(*) Alas, if b is "small", or if enough is known about b that the remaining unknown portion is "small",
most convergent encryption algorithms allow some attacker to reveal b by
exhaustively enumerating all possible messages m, until the attacker finds some message where y = E(b) == z = E(m), and therefore the attacker has revealed that b == m.
In particular, for Mental Poker,
if Alice sets "b" to be some 2-byte representation of a single card, then publishes y = E(b),
Mallory could probably discover which particular card pretty rapidly.

Fortunately, in practice, it's often possible to make b large enough and with enough unknowns that it is impractical to apply this attack.
In particular, for Mental Poker,
If Alice sets "c" to a freshly-generated 256-bit random number concatenated with some 2-byte representation of a single card, then publishes w = E(c),
it appears to be infeasible for Mallory to gain any more information about which card c that Alice picked.

Comment: Alas, if that is done, then it is no longer simple to prove -- without revealing the 256-bit random $\hspace{0.8 in}$ number or the private key -- that the cards represented are equal. $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer: I'm no poker expert, but I don't follow. If Alice wants to prove that message A (the ace of hearts with a freshly-generated 256-bit random number) is the same as message B (also the ace of hearts with the same 256-bit random number), can't she simply point out that X and Y are identical, without revealing the 256-bit random number or her private key or the fact that A represents the ace of hearts?

Comment: Yes, but using the same 256-bit random number to get ciphertext B would mean that the 256-bit random number used to get ciphertext B was not fresh. $\:$ (And now a see that I'd accidentally typed "number" in my first comment, instead of "numbers".) $\;\;$

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in 2012, and it's a good example of how zk proof technology has improved in the subsequent decade or so. In 2024 the answer can be straightforwardly: use a general-purpose zk-SNARK such as PLONK or Halo 2 to prove the statement $$\{ (x, y, pk): \exists (r, r', a) \text{ such that} \\ E_{pk,r}(a) = x \wedge E_{pk,r'}(a) = y \}$$ directly for any, in principle arbitrary, public key encryption scheme. ($r$ and $r'$ here are the random inputs to each encryption. In practice you also want to be explicit about the types when instantiating this for a particular $E$.)

That's not to say it's trivial: the circuit will be more efficient and easier to audit if the encryption scheme and zk-SNARK parameters are chosen to make it easier to express the encryption (for example, if $E$ is an elliptic curve encryption scheme using an embedded curve for the proof system). And it is still the case that a specialized encryption scheme and specialized proof, as suggested in the other answers, could be more efficient.

On the other hand, a general-purpose zk-SNARK comes into its own in terms of extensibility: we can relatively easily add constraints to the statement that would be all-but-impossible for a specialized construction.