# A question or few about Mental Poker

Tags: protocol-design, algorithm-design, mental-poker

I have spent some time studying the "Mental Poker" protocol (sometimes
called SRA), initially proposed by Shamir, Rivest, and Adleman --
http://people.csail.mit.edu/~rivest/ShamirRivestAdleman-MentalPoker.pdf

Much of the current literature surrounding SRA deals with
implementations, most of which seek to address specific problems like
handling of the virtual card deck, player dropouts, and so on. I 
understand these to be protocol problems, not algorithmic problems or
problems specific to the cryptosystem (algorithm + key generation and 
management). I'm interested in finding flaws or weaknesses within 
the cryptosystem.

So far I've noted:

- Information leakage via quadratic residues / non-residues with a prime
  modulus (Legendre symbol)
- Unpadded or poorly padded "plaintext" numerical values
- Potentially novel approaches to the discrete logarithm problem (such as
  http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-55220-5_1)
- Short key lengths (similar to RSA key-pair bit lengths)
- Use of a composite modulus rather than a prime
- Weak Pseudo-Random Number Generator

Assuming one can sufficiently address known performance issues (like
Crepeau's 8-hour-long card deal), does SRA have additional known
weaknesses or drawbacks? Would some RSA caveats apply here too?

I noted the answer to [What is the theoretical and practical status of mental poker?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/what-is-the-theoretical-and-practical-status-of-mental-poker). This was an 
excellent reply but I did not notice mention of specific publications 
such as Don Coppersmith's "Cheating at Mental Poker".

I appreciate your comments.